# Using android phone as a second screen

Tags: keyboard, multiple-monitors, mouse, android, remote

There are many options in the market and in the community about virtual desktop and remote control, but until now I haven't seen any solution to be able to just control the smartphone (android) just using the computer mouse under the linux, as if it were a second monitor, but each screen operating your operational system.

If there's any way to do this in Linux, for those who need to keep this constant flow between Desktop and Mobile, it would be a perfect solution to just leave the phone aside and control it as if it were an external monitor (*without needing to mirror the image on the monitor, because the phone will be already positioned on the side*)

Comment: A search for VNC Server on Google Play gives some apps. I have not tested any.

Comment: But that's the problem, basically all of theses Virtual Desktops solutions (VNCs, GUI Remote Control) have the option to mirror the screen using a program window as receiver. 

This question is exactly to know if have a solution to do a better workflow between PC and Android, because if we have the phone positioned on our side, we don't need a graphical feedback occupying the computer screen, this could be something more dynamic like moving the cursor to the right (like a 2nd monitor) but instead of mirroring it, to have mouse/keyboard on Android remotely, to see in the phone at our side.

Comment: perhaps a remote desktop app might work, try "Screen Sharing" and "Remmina" in Ubuntu.

Comment: Chekc also ... https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy. However also in a Window.

Comment: Thanks @C.S.Cameron and pLumo but, as I said, the question isn't to just open a remote control as a mirrored window of the Android phone to operate (unfortunatelly 24601 removed the final of the question about "to set as a 2nd screen [or something like, without GUI] to just control [the android] with mouse and keyboard")

Comment: Not sure if [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy/) has an Android Client. They had one, but it seems it is not anymore supported.